# Customize tabs android

Tags: android, background, tabs, customization

This is how I want the tabs to look:

http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/5696/tabort.png

This is how they look using tabHost:

http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/1030/tabort2.png

So I want to remove the border around the images. Instead, I want to have the greyish background image behind the tabs. Can anyone please help me with this (I'm new to Android)?

Here is some relevant code:

```
// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab 
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, WashActivity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("washer").setIndicator("",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.wash_tab))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Buttons positioned side-by-side in Relative Layout with custom background images instead of TabView.

Comment: OK I've done this, but how do I switch between different activities using onClick-listeners? Do I use Intent() like with tabHost?

Comment: Yes, you can use Intent. Intents are always used to travel from one activity to another irrespective of TabHost.

Answer (score 1):

set custom view ( imageview or image with text in ur case ) using setView() instead setIndicator() will work for you .

TabHost is deprecated now . so better to use fragment with compatibility package .